# Not able to import custom module in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I had a project in my machine earlier and it was compiling perfectly. Now when I changed my machine and configured my project in my pyCharm, I am not able to import custom modules which I created in another project.

[image]

As you can see I don't see import option in the drop down menu.

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

How do you run this code outside of PyCharm? Do you add the second project to `PYTHONPATH` manually or install it with a `pip`? A possible workaround is to add the second project as a content root in **Settings | Project ... | Project Structure** or as a new entry in interpreter paths:

[image]